# What's the maximum size of the garden so I can ask questions here?

Tags: discussion

Say I have a big garden, 3,000 square meters. Is it too big?

How about one hectare?

What if I buy one hectare of land, I make there a small house and I live there, and make a garden on that 1 hectare of land, growing tomato, pepper, lettuce, radish and other vegetables (horticulture)

Can I ask questions here about such a garden?

my question is inspired by another question:
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/does-gardening-and-landscaping-only-include-outdoor-plants-or-indoor-plants-aswe

Should I have asked it somewhere else? If that's the case, I apologize for that and please tell me where to post the question.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the size of the piece of land that determines whether or not it's on-topic, it's the use that you put the land to. Our [FAQ for on- and off-topic](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions says that questions about

> large scale agriculture and/or the business of gardening,

are off-topic.

Your questions would be on-topic if they're about **growing** the crops you mentioned. They would start to be off-topic if you were asking about harvesting 5000 tomato plants every day, or transporting your crops to market without them getting damaged (for example).

Comment: I still think that qualification may hurt this site and keep it's active users smaller than it otherwise might.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is difficult to answer because there are too many variables and it's not 100% clear what you're asking. "Too big" for what? You say if you build a 'small' house, but that means we don't know the footprint of the house in terms of measurements. You don't say what sort of horticulture you mean - professional, meaning you're going to have, say, lots of polytunnels and produce food for sale, or whether you mean you just want a veggie patch that's big enough to feed your family.

Probably, in terms of food gardening, its best to ask the ideal size of plot for the type of foods you want to grow, which means saying what they are; also saying whether you want ornamental gardening space, lakes, hills, rivers, avenues, a forest, a wood, a wildflower meadow, an olympic sized swimming pool,acres of lawn or whether you just want a medium to large garden to plant.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is too small or too large.  You won't get a simple answer either way!  One has to go through a process where WANTS, NEEDS, fit what you own or can use.  Take pictures, define exactly what you have, what you want to use and as best you can, what you would like to create.

How much you are willing to invest in installation, maintenance...

I am sure that if you added as much information as you could imagine YOU would need to make these decisions...you would get incredible ideas from this site!

Send a rough plan of what you have, what you've done, what didn't work, what did work...and where you'd like to go.  Include orientation, microenvironmental details...anything YOU would need to generate ideas!

Tell us who you are, your ideas...as much as you are able!